# Accessing firebase object with python and get 'DatetimeWithNanoseconds' object has no attribute 'ToDatetime'

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am writing a simple cloud function to find the new objects in firebase. I was using the following function;

```
def users_and_tours(event, context):
    today = datetime.now()
    query_tours = db.collection('tours')
    query_users = db.collection('users')


    #avg_num_signed_up_per_day
    emails = {}
    for doc in query_users.stream():
        created_date = doc.create_time.ToDatetime()
        since_creation = (today - created_date).days
```

This use to work, I didn't change the cloud function but now I get this error
**line 31, in users_and_tours created_date = doc.create_time.ToDatetime() AttributeError: 'DatetimeWithNanoseconds' object has no attribute 'ToDatetime''**

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your function code did not change, you should look on the content that is accessed by the Cloud Function.

My understanding looking at the [Python api for this object](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/_modules/google/api_core/datetime_helpers.html#DatetimeWithNanoseconds) is that it [never](https://github.com/googleapis/python-api-core/search?q=todatetime) had `ToDatetime`.

Can you indicate your `requirements.txt` as well as a screen shot of what the object `user` is in the Firestore console?